# Arcs on a plane in 3-D drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to do the following figure using TikZ:

http://wstaw.org/m/2012/12/23/zeichnung.png

I would know how to to this using `\clip`, `\draw`, `arc` and `\draw[->]` in 2D. But how can I draw this on a plane that lies in the x-z plane?

Comment: May be the [`tikz-3dplot` package](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf) could be useful.

Comment: Could you please post a minimal example to get people started, using the commands you mentioned? It's no fun to start from scratch, but with the framework in place, it will be quite easy to get this into the x-z plane.

Comment: @Jake: True, but I learned a lot going through the documentation myself. I posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `tikz-3dplot` package totally rocks. I just drew my picture in the x-y-plane and rotated it then. The only caveat is that `rectangle` does not work any more, one has to supply all four corners by hand.

http://wstaw.org/m/2012/12/24/zeichnung.png

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{200}

    \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
        \draw (0, 0) -- (5, 0) -- (5, 5) -- (0, 5) -- cycle;
        \node[below right] at (0, 5) {$\R^3$};

        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0, 0) -- (5, 0) -- (5, 5) -- (0, 5) -- cycle;
            \fill[opacity=20, color=black!20] ($(1, 1)+(45:3)+(0.5, 0)$) arc (0:360:0.5);
            \begin{scope}[->, thick]
                \draw (1, 1) -- ++(60:3) node[midway, below] {$t$};
                \draw (1, 1) -- ++(100:2.5) node[midway, right] {$t_0$};
                \draw (1, 1) -- ++(30:3.5) node[midway, below] {$t_1$};
                \draw (1, 1) -- ++(0:1.5) node[midway, above] {$t$};
            \end{scope}
            \draw (4, 1) arc (0:360:3);
            \draw (3.5, 1) arc (0:360:2.5);
            \draw (4.5, 1) arc (0:360:3.5);
            \draw (2.5, 1) arc (0:360:1.5);
        \end{scope}

        \draw[thick, ->] (5, 5, 0) -- ++(0, 0, 2) node[sloped, midway, above] {Zeitachse};  
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```